# ng-value not updating the value in uib-datepicker when it has been changed in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am showing some data of date in my frontend.It was working fine when we refresh the page to see the updated value but when we are not refreshing the page and changing the value from backend it is not getting updated in the uib-datepicker input field SOMETIMES.
I have consoled the variable which is written in my uib-datepicker's ng-value directive and that object is getting updated but it is not getting refresh in uib-datepicker input field

```
<input style="padding: 1px;padding-left: 2px;font-size: 75%" 
                            type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" is-open="popup[$index].open" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" ng-value="fx.test" id="fxtest{{$index}}" ng-model="vm.test[$index]" ng-change="vm.updateData(null,null,vm.test[$index],$index,fx._id)"  close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" readonly="readonly" />
```

When I am outputting fx.test with {{}} brackets and it is showing the correct updated value but uib-datepicker is not showing the correct value.

Comment: please give some sample code to check with, anyway most likely, digest cycle is not run. So may be you are changing ng-model based on a mechanism which is out of angular environment for example jQuery. Try calling $apply after update or be sure to be in angular environment

Comment: updated my post with code.

Comment: avoid using ng-value for non radio, select inputs, it is similar to ng-init in other cases, use ng-modal to update.

Comment: It is getting updated on frontend.When I display it with {{}} it is showing the updated value but datepicker is somehow not updating the value.

Comment: which is your date value?

Comment: yes @AmeerPappay in dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: update some code on what u are doing